# Why doesn't PyHamcrest have a negative equality matcher?

Tags: python, equals, hamcrest, pyhamcrest

Reviewing [PyHamcrest's API](http://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/object_matchers/), I see there's an `equal_to` matcher

```
from hamcrest import *
assert_that('1', equal_to('1'))
```

but there's no parallel negative method such as `not_equal_to`

```
from hamcrest import *
assert_that('1', not_equal_to('2'))
```

What's the proper way of matching negative equality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way to match for negative equality is to chain the `equal_to` method with the `is_not` method

```
from hamcrest import *
assert_that('1', is_not(equal_to('1')))
```